# Confusion about Decision / Condition testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

[image]

For this function, i'm trying to write test sets that that cover Decision, then another set that covers Condition. I'm having trouble differentiating the two. For condition coverage, I have this:

> Test case 1: A = 3, B = 4, C = 1  :: Line 4  True / True
>
> Test case 2: A = 3, B = 4 C = 5  :: Line 4  True / False
>
> Test case 3: A = 4, B = 3, C = 1 :: Line 4  False / True
>
> Test case 4: A = 3, B = 4, C= 3 :: Line 5  True / True
>
> Test case 5: A = 3, B = 4, C = 1 :: Line 5 True / False
>
> Test case 6: A = 3, B = 3, C = 1 :: Line 5 False / False
>
> Test case 7: A = 3, B =3, C = 3 :: Line 6 True / True
>
> Test case 8: A = 3, B = 3, C = 1 :: Line 6 True / False
>
> Test case 9: A = 3, B = 10, C = 1:: Line 6 False / False

Would this be correct for condition coverage?

EDIT --------------

This is my Decision coverage:

> Test case 1: A = 4, B = 6, C = 2
>
> Test case 2: A = 4, B = 6, C = 4
>
> Test case3: A = 4,  B = 2, C = 4

Is this correct for Decision?